# Determining date for Quaker wedding?

Tags: date, quakers

A wedding invitation states:

> Fourth day, fourth month eleventh

What is the date for a non Quaker guest?

Answer (score 2):

Quakers did not like to use the weekdays and months that were named after Pagan gods, therefore they used numbers instead.

- Fourth day = Wednesday (the first day being Sunday)
- Fourth month = April (assuming this is after the adoption of the Gregorian or New Style calendar, which was 1752 in the British Isles)

Thus the date being referred to was Wednesday, April 11th.

A nice summary of Quaker calendar customs can be found at the [Friends Historical Library website](http://www.swarthmore.edu/friends-historical-library/quaker-calendar).